# JPA Eclipselink getReference not throwing EntityNotFoundException after static weaving

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I am attempting to implement static weaving in order to use lazy fetching of OneToOne and ManyToOne relationships in a Java SE environment.  I followed the approach outlined here: https://flexguse.wordpress.com/2013/08/10/maven-spring-data-jpa-eclipselink-and-static-weaving/ and was able to get OneToOne and ManyToOne relationships to be lazy loaded.  However, one strange side effect is calling EntityManager.getReference() no longer throws an EntityNotFoundException if that entity does not exist.  If I access the returned entity in any way, such as calling a getter, it does throw the exception.  Any thoughts on what is causing this change in behavior?

Comment: getReference allows returning a proxy or lazy reference instead of actually looking up the entity,  EclipseLink's weaving allows it to return an instance that will trigger the fetch later on,  delaying the exception.  Use find instead.

Comment: That worked thanks Chris.  Find does not throw an exception but returns null if an entity is not found, but that change in functionality can be easily handled.